# will JPQL NEW operator create object manged by persistence context?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
TypedQuery<MemberDTO> query=
  entityManager.createQuery("select new com.java.DTO.MemberDTO(m.id,m.username) from Member m",MemberDTO.class);
MemberTDO memberDTO= query.getSingleREsult();
```

if I did like above, would memberDTO be managed by persistence context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the `MemberDTO` will be simple Java object.

But be careful if you pass Entity objects to the constructor then these entities will be managed.

Comment: so you mean 
if I did like this 

createQuery("SOME QUERY",SOME ENTITY OBJECT);
if would return managed entity right?

Comment: If you do new com.java.DTO.MemberDTO(m.id,m) then m will be managed